# Tethering breaks internet providing

Tags: android, tethering

I do internet sharing via wi-fi hotspot created on Samsung S8 Android phone. After some time Windows 10 client stops getting internet. Wifi is still connected, but no internet. Browsing internet on phone restores internet providing on hotspot. How to keep alive internet on hotspot?

Comment: Is tethering allowed by your cell phone account service agreement? Some cell service providers drop or throttle the connection if you suck too much data in a short space of time.

Comment: Some service providers even try to detect if you are tethering a PC based on the traffic. Would be interesting if you could also restore network using an emulated Android system on the PC instead of using the real phone.

Comment: My  UK cell provider's web site (1) says tethering is not supported (2) has a page of tethering instructions. I think the idea is that you may be OK with short, infrequent connections, with light data use, but if you hammer it they'll cap you, and you can't complain.